# partial derivative, minimize $m_1^2 + 1/(s^2)\times\sum_{i=1}(y_i - m_0 - m_1\times t_i - m_2*t_i^2)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-derivative

I'm struggling to solve and minimise a derivative with respect to $m_1$. This is the expression I need to derivative:

> $$m_1^2 + 1/(s^2)\times\sum_{i=1}(y_i - m_0 - m_1\times t_i - m_2\times t_i^2)^2$$

To minimize, I set the derivative equal to $0$. I need to get an expression for $m_1$ which I did until this point:

> $$m_1 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}t_i(y_i-m_0-m2\times t_i^2)}{(s^2) + m_1\times\sum_{i=1}t_i^2} $$

but I can't  get rid of the $m_1$ in the denominator or perhaps I made a mistake before, but I don't see where.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I found an error when the chain rule was applied, so that $m1$ shouldn't be in the denominator. so, it's

$$m_1 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}t_i(y_i-m_0-m2\times t_i^2)}{(s^2) + \sum_{i=1}t_i^2} $$